# how to do the XOR operation between two hexa strings?

Tags: ruby, xor

I have two hexadecimal strings.I need to do the `XOR` operation between them.

My hexa strings Like,

```
 a = "1A6F2D31567C80644A5BEF2D50B986B";
 b = "EF737F481FC7CDAE7C8B40837C80644";
```

How to do the XOR operation between them?
Can you give some guideline to do that?

Comment: the output is an integer or another string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would work for any base:

```
>> (a.to_i(16) ^ b.to_i(16)).to_s(16) 
=> "f51c527949bb4dca36d0afae2c39e2f"
```

But you can use [String#hex](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-hex) for hexadecimal strings.

Answer (score 9):

```
a = "1A6F2D31567C80644A5BEF2D50B986B"
b = "EF737F481FC7CDAE7C8B40837C80644"
a.hex ^ b.hex
#or (a.hex ^ b.hex).to_s(16)
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specifically ask, but you might want the output String to be the same length as the input Strings by **padding leading zeros**.  So, building on steenslag's slick answer (and adjusting the input values to illustrate the potential problem):

```
a = "14ef"
b = "1ca3"
(a.hex ^ b.hex).to_s(16)
# "84c"
(a.hex ^ b.hex).to_s(16).rjust(a.length, '0')
# "084c"
```